# How do I override fab element css in onsen ui?

Tags: css, angular, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I cannot get the onsen fab element to change background color or border. I'm using angular 2 and onsen v2. If I uncheck the fabs default css in the browser inspector I see my css applied. I already tried !important.

Here is my css

```
.main-counter-remove{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    color: #d9534f !important;
}

.main-counter-add{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold !important;
    color: #5cb85c !important;

}

.main-counter-remove.fab{
    border: 2px !important;
    border-color: #d9534f !important;
    background-color: white;
}
.main-counter-add.fab{
    border: 2px !important;
    border-color: #5cb85c !important;
    background-color: white;
}
```

This is my html

```
        <div class="main-counter-remove">
            <ons-fab modifier="mini" (click)="decrementMainCounter()">
                <span>-</span>
            </ons-fab>
        </div>
        <div class="main-counter">
            <p style="padding:5px">10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="main-counter-add">
            <ons-fab modifier="mini" (click)="incrementMainCounter()">
                <span>+</span>
            </ons-fab>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you showthe browser's css inspector for one of the fab element?

Comment: here is the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/6LGszuT.png

Comment: What's the viewencapsultation value for your component?

Answer (score 0):

The fab class is applied to a child element of `main-content-remove`

Try that

```
.main-counter-remove .fab/* note the space */
{ 
     /* rules here */
}
```